# Lost my file in linux

Tags: linux, console

In linux terminal, I accidentally mistyped
 `sudo mv myfile.zip /~`
My purpose was to move under the home folder but it was not there.
Although I tried to find it by both
 `sudo find / -name 'myfile.zip'`
and
 `sudo locate myfile.zip`
could not find it. Where  it can be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably belongs on superuser.

Comment: locate, slocate and mlocate usually require you to make the locate database up-to-date with `sudo updatedb`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be surprised to find a file named `~` right under `/`.

Answer (score 4):

It's called `/~`. That's a perfectly valid filename (remember, shell only expands `~` at the * beginning* of a path and you typed it in the middle, so the shell left it at that).

Answer (score 3):

You moved it to `/~` --- it is at root and named `~`.

Answer (score 3):

Your file is now no longer named `myfile.zip`, but `~`.  You should find it exactly where you told it to go, at: `/~`

Answer (score 2):

It will be under `/` and its name will be `~`.

You'll be surprised that unlike Windows, Unix-like systems can take a lot of things very literally, you can even create a file with the name `*.*` if you quote properly. The system won't complain about it, and it will even work.